# Stop windows services not listed in input file

Tags: windows, file-io, service, vbscript

I am new to VBS scripting and I am wanting to script the stopping of Windows services other than a core set of services. I have currently written a bit of code that will query all local services and output to a text file their running state, I then wish to read from an input file a list of core services NOT to stop however to stop the rest of the services running on that machine. I would like this to be a generic input file so if a service is listed however is not installed on the server for it to continue onto the next service to stop.

Not sure how to proceed with this, would I need to read the input file into an array then do an IF statement to say if objService.Name not equal to the array (somehow) then to stop the service?

Code below - thanks in advance for any assistance/tips

```
Const ForAppending = 8  

strComputer = "." 

strLogPath = "C:\Scripts"

strServicesLog = strLogPath & Replace(Wscript.ScriptName,".vbs","") & ".txt"

Set objWMISvc = GetObject( "winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2" )

Set colItems = objWMISvc.ExecQuery( "Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem", , 48)

' // Create Output Logs folder for script

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objTS = objFS.CreateTextFile(strServicesLog, True)

objTS.Write "******************************************************************" & vbcrlf

objTS.Write (Replace(Wscript.ScriptName,".vbs","") & " audit log") & vbcrlf

objTS.Write ("Execution Start: " & FormatDateTime(Now(),2) &  "  " & 

FormatDateTime(Now(),3)) & vbcrlf

For Each objItem in colItems

    strComputerName = objItem.Name

    objTS.Write vbCrlf & "Server Name: " & strComputerName & vbCrlf

Next

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & 

strComputer & "\root\cimv2")  

Set colRunningServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery _  

    ("Select * from Win32_Service")  

For Each objService in colRunningServices  

   objTS.Write "Display Name: " & vbTab & (objService.DisplayName) & vbCrlf

   objTS.Write "Service Name: " & vbTab & (objService.Name) & vbCrlf  

   objTS.Write "Service State: " & vbTab & (objService.State) & vbCrlf 

   objTS.Write "Start Mode: " & vbTab & (objService.StartMode) & vbCrlf  

   objTS.WriteLine  

Next  

objTS.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read your list of services into a Dictionary object. The Dictionary class has an `Exists()` method that you can use to test if a string/key exists.

Here's how to read a list of strings (services) from a file named `c:\input.txt` into a dictionary:

```
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set objFileIn = objFS.OpenTextFile("c:\input.txt")

Do Until objFileIn.AtEndOfStream
    strService = objFileIn.ReadLine()
    If Len(strService) > 0 Then If Not d.Exists(strService) Then d.Add strService, ""
Loop
```

Later, when you're iterating the list of services on the computer, check the service name against your dictionary:

```
For Each objService in colRunningServices

    ' If this service is not in the list of core services, stop it...
    If Not d.Exists(objService.Name) Then objService.StopService

Next
```